# Authentication options for accessing Solace PubSub+ Manager

Tags: basic-authentication, solace

Currently to access the Solace PubSub+ Manager, we log in with a user id and password using a web browser. The authentication method used is "Basic Authentication". Are there any other options available?

I understand that clients to the messaging services can authenticate with Basic, Certificate, Kerberos, and OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

No, we don't have any other options, other than Basic authentication scheme for now to login to Pub Sub+ Manager.